# Ionic side menu child state not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

Here is a fork of the ionic starter template side menu:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8xZqCTqIUIymbSUOe9tR?p=preview

I wanted to change the state definition from:

```
'app.single'
```

to

```
'app.playlists.single'
```

So it becomes the child of playlists and I have access to parent $scope.

**Why does this not work?**

Neither **$state.go('app.playlists.single')** nor **href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}"** works anymore.

Nothing happens when you click the link as you see in the plunker

It starts working when I change it back to :

```
.state('app.single', {
      url: "/playlists/:playlistId",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "playlist.html",
          controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
        }
      }
 });
```

Comment: in your plunkr where is your playlistId